# Can i bypass the builtin rectifier and directly supply dc to my microphone preamp and reverb board

Tags: operational-amplifier, microphone

I currently have this [mic preamp and reverb board](https://s.lazada.com.ph/s.Dt5X) that accepts 12-0-12 ac:

[image: pt2399 mic preamp]

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaMae.png)

I have a 24v 10a switching supply and i found a way to create a 12-0-12 dc using this [tutorial on youtube](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Mk8TN9OjywM)

Would it be possible to bypass the built in rectifier and just use my diy dual dc circuit? Thanks

Comment: Please link to a datasheet with a circuit diagram for the part. If there is none then the question is likely to be closed as we don't offer technical support for cheap shopping sites. "No datasheet? No sale!"

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to bypass anything; the rectifier will pass DC just fine.

The amplifier will operate at reduced power, mainly because the AC voltage measurement is an RMS measurement, which means that the peak voltage produced at the  output of the rectifier is more like ±16 V.

To get full power, you need a power supply that can put out a total of 34 V.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help